# Why do I have to reload my page to get navigation bar in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a navigation bar in app.component.html After I log in I'm taken to either employee home page or manager home page depending on the role I select. But when my home page opens in the browser, the navbar is hidden and I have to reload the page to make it visible. Please, help me.

I m including `app.component.ts`, `app.component.html` and `login.ts` files below.

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from './_services';
import { User } from './_models';

@Component({ selector: 'app', templateUrl: 'app.component.html' })
export class AppComponent {
    currentUser: User;
    flag=false;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
        ) {
        this.authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => {
            this.currentUser = x
            if(this.currentUser.role=="Employee"){
                this.flag=true;
                console.log(this.flag)
            }
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this.authenticationService.logout();
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<!-- nav -->
<div *ngIf="flag">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark" *ngIf="currentUser">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/">{{currentUser.role}}</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="applyforleave" >Apply for Leave</a> 
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="my-leaves">My Leaves</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="check-leaves">Leave record</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!flag">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark" *ngIf="currentUser">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/manager-home">{{currentUser.role}}</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="leave-request">Leave request</a>
            <!--<a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="manager-home">Manager-Home</a>-->  
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<!-- main app container-->
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

> login.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_services';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'login.component.html' })
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;
    returnUrl: string;
    error = '';

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
        ) { 
            // redirect to home if already logged in
            if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) { 
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            }
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                username: ['', Validators.required],
                password: ['', Validators.required],
                role: ['', Validators.required]
            });

            // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
            // this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
        }

        // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
        get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

        onSubmit() {
            this.submitted = true;

            // stop here if form is invalid
            if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
                return;
            }

            this.loading = true;
            this.authenticationService
                .login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value, this.f.role.value)
                .pipe(first())
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        if(this.f.role.value=="Employee"){
                            this.router.navigate(['/']);
                        }
                        if(this.f.role.value=="Manager"){
                           this.router.navigate(['/manager-home'])
                       }
                   },
                   error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.loading = false;
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: why are you checking currentUser ? can you please provide stackblitz link ?

Comment: move the subscribe to a ngOnInit, and insteadOf *ngIf="currentUser", use the safe operator {{currentUser?.role}} to see the nav-bar at first (well, without user, but you can see "something" while the authentication happens)

Comment: can you provide source of authentication service?